# QSignalMapper does not trigger mapped

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qsignalmapper

I've recently encoutered a problem with QSignalMapper. I can't get the signal mapped (QObject*) to trigger

I currently have a qml object `keyboard.qml` allocated and removed from a c++ class `keyboardManager.cpp`. In `keyboard.qml` I have the following signals:

```
signal keyboardOpening
signal keyboardOpened
signal keyboardClosing
signal keyboardClosed
```

and this function:

```
function close() {
    popDelay.stop();
    closing = true;
    keyboardClosing();
    state = "OFFSCREEN";
}
```

the signal

```
signal keyboardClosed
```

is triggered when all animations related to the state change are finished

In c++ I have a method and a slot

```
//method
void KeyboardManager::beginRemoveKeyboard(TouchTextField *target);
//slot
void KeyboardManager::endRemoveKeyboard(QObject *target);
```

In beginRemoveKeyboard I try to connect keyboardClosed to endRemoveKeyboard so I can free my memory and unregister all pointers properly so I did this test:

in QML:

```
onKeyboardClosed: console.debug("closed");
```

in C++:

```
void KeyboardManager::test() { qDebug() << "test"; }
void KeyboardManager::beginRemoveKeyboard(TouchTextField *target)
{
    NewKeyboard *currentKeyboard = m_keyboards.value(target);

    QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    QObject::connect(currentKeyboard, SIGNAL(keyboardClosed()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    QObject::connect(currentKeyboard, SIGNAL(keyboardClosed()), this, SLOT(test()));
    signalMapper->setMapping(this, (QObject*)target);

    QObject::connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QObject*)), this, SLOT(endRemoveKeyboard(QObject*)));
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(currentKeyboard, "close");
}
void KeyboardManager::endRemoveKeyboard(QObject *target)
{
    qDebug() << "deletion started";
    TouchTextField* actualTarget = qobject_cast<TouchTextField*>(target);
    NewKeyboard *currentKeyboard = m_keyboards.value(actualTarget);
    actualTarget->setKeyboard(NULL);
    m_keyboards.remove(actualTarget);
    delete currentKeyboard;
    if (sender())
        delete sender(); //QSignalMapper
}
```

however when I called KeyboardManager::beginRemoveKeyboard and got:

```
[DEBUG]closed (qrc:///main.qml:24, )
[DEBUG] test (tmp/debug/moc/../../../include/keyboard/KeyboardManager.h:31, void KeyboardManager::test())
```

and that's all. no "deletion started" which mean that `KeyboardClosed()` is triggered, `test()` is called but `endRemoveKeyboard(QObject*)` is not. Why and how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you solve the problem if you put the line `signalMapper->setMapping(this, (QObject*)target);` after `QObject::connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QObject*)), this, SLOT(endRemoveKeyboard(QObject*)));`?

Comment: I just tried  QObject::connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QObject*)), this, SLOT(endRemoveKeyboard(QObject*)));
    signalMapper->setMapping(this, (QObject*)target); still not working

Comment: Try to set `signalMapper` as a member variable, not a local variable. Maybe it's due to the pointer is deleted when `KeyboardManager::beginRemoveKeyboard` ends.

Comment: still not working. I decided to create a class that basically do the same thing as QSignalMapper and it works now. Thanks for your help, at least you tried too.

Comment: OK, but... Sorry :( anyway, thanks to you and happy coding!